# JPA slow query with multiple EJB Projects

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

I used to have 1 Project with EJB and PersistenceUnit in my EAR and it worked fine, queries run at << 1s.

When I create an extra EJB project and define a new PU on it, the whole EAR project run queries that involve retrieving entity very slowly.

For example:

The `em.find(Record.class, "SomeID")` take up to 10 seconds to complete.

```
SELECT r FROM Record r WHERE r.ID = :ID
```

takes about the same time as `find` to complete, and every other table containing ~10000 data takes about the same but

```
SELECT r.somePrimitiveAttribute FROM Record r WHERE r.ID = :ID
```

takes only milliseconds.

In persistence.xml I just specified database url/password/username and a list of class name  without any other parameter.

As the query delay rendering of webpage to about 10s per page, it is not acceptable even for testing.
Can anyone suggest what setting should I use to stop EclipseLink 2.3.x from slowing down? I will provide further details as much as I can if needed.

Comment: Enable sql query logging & verify the query

Comment: Please verify that if Record class has relationships then they are being lazily loaded. Also looking at the generated sql will help. You can configure eclipselink to log your sql and also output the parameters send in sql.If that too does not help then enable the debug log for eclipselink and see what's its doing underneath.

Comment: I am using websphere 8.5 and I can never make logging work for me. Logs did not appear on eclipse and not on websphere JVM log either.

Comment: I just realized that the log was not in stdout, but a trace.log. I spotted a query that select from 14 table and took 5700ms to execute, that seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup the correct Dialect for your database on persistence.xml.